# curl post complains that a radio button has not been selected

Tags: php, html, url, curl

I am trying to submit a form using curl, the problem is the form has a radio button and when I try to post the correct value of the radio button I get the error "An option has not been selected", this of course refers to the radio button.

I'm not sure why this is happening but is there anywhere around this problem?

**HTML radio button portion:**

```
<div class="choices">
    <label>
        <img src="/images/1.gif" alt="1" height="25"/>
        <input name="s_method" type="radio" id="a" value="a" /> 
    </label>
</div>

<div class="choices">
    <label>
        <img src="/images/2.gif" alt="2" height="25"/>
        <input name="s_method" type="radio" id="b" value="b" /> 
    </label>
</div>

<div class="choices">
    <label>
        <img src="/images/3.gif" alt="3" height="25"/>
        <input name="s_method" type="radio" id="c" value="c" /> 
    </label>
</div>
```

**post url:**

```
www.example.com/process/s1?s_method=a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example url you have provided is doing http GET operation. But you need to do it through http POST. Here is appropriate curl code for your POST.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.example.com/process/s1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "s_method=a");
```